# How to append Excel worksheet to existing tables in Access in VB?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have created a userform to import a single excel worksheet to a specific excel table. I did it exactly from the youtube tutorial step by step. However, it runs into

> "Compile Error: Method of data not found" for `Me.txtFileName`

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnBrowse_Click()
    Dim diag As Office.FileDialog
    Dim item As Variant

    Set diag = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    diag.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diag.Title = "Please select an Excel Spreadsheet"
    diag.Filters.Clear
    diag.Filters.Add "Excel Spreadsheet", "*.xls, *.xlsx"
    If diag.Show Then
        For Each item In diag.SelectedItems
            Me.txtFileName = item
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `txtFileName` in your Userform ?

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean. This is the FileName I wish to "see" in my dialog, and it gives me the "Compile Error: Method of data not found" whenever I try to debug it or run it.

Comment: `txtFileName` should be the name of a textbox on your form. Did you add one with that name?

Comment: thank you, I think it's the txtFileName is the issue here because it's not linked to the actual box I want it add, problem solved once I add it with that name!

Answer (score 0):

I think the line `Me.txtFileName = item` doesn't make any sense in your code.

You were not even allowing multiple select, so the Loop in the end was Pointless. I have amended it a little bit. Now you will see msgbox after selecting multiple Files.

You can change that Msgbox line to anywhere you want to print those file names that are being selected in the Diag.

```
Private Sub btnBrowse_Click()
    Dim diag As Office.FileDialog
    Dim item As Variant

    Set diag = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    diag.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diag.Title = "Please select an Excel Spreadsheet"
    diag.Filters.Clear
    diag.Filters.Add "Excel Spreadsheet", "*.xls, *.xlsx"
    diag.AllowMultiSelect = True
    If diag.Show Then
        For Each item In diag.SelectedItems
            MsgBox item
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

For starters, when the dialog appears, select only 2 files.

Comment: Great, now it works like a charm. thanks for the help!